# Tensorflow Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'

Tags: python, tensorflow

Running on MacOS, Catalina.

Other Details:

- Jupyter Notebook
- `!pip install --no-deps keras==2.2.4`
- `!pip install --no-deps tensorflow==1.15.3`
- Python Version 3.7
- Following virtually step-by-step from: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-train-an-object-detection-model-with-keras/

Anyone encounter this error / know how to resolve?

Comment: I believe `tensorflow-estimator` is a separate package, and if you install with `--no-deps`, you won't get that package. Try installing without `--no-deps`.

Comment: Getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by restarting Jupyter Notebook kernel. Consulted various resources online to install / uninstall packages and items, so difficult to pinpoint was produced the desired result -- but for those encountering this, ensure to restart kernel.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, in my Anaconda virtual environment running Python 3.7, I have fixed this issue by simply upgrading TensorFlow and Keras to the latest versions.

I did this by running the following PIP command in my Anaconda terminal:

```
pip install tensorflow --user --upgrade
pip install keras --user --upgrade
```